# Firebase returns "app/bad-app-name" in angularfire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

In my Angular app Firebase returns an error which shows `bad-app-name` as code.
i'm using angularfire2 in angular app.

I have double checked Firebase configuration, it is alright, so how to solve this error.

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  courses: any[];
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    db.list('/Courses').valueChanges().subscribe(courses => {
      this.courses = courses;
      console.log(this.courses);
    });
  }

  login() {
    this.isLoggedIn = !this.isLoggedIn;
  }
  user:any;
  saveData(formData) {
    if (formData.valid) {
      console.log(formData.value);
    }
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "angularfire2/database";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "angularfire2/auth";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "apikey",
  authDomain: "angular-f5fa9.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://angular-f5fa9.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "angular-f5fa9",
  storageBucket: "angular-f5fa9.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "592083773091"
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Console Error**

```
FirebaseError {
code: "app/bad-app-name", 
message: "Firebase: Illegal App name: '[object Object] (app/bad-app-name).", 
name: "[object Object]", 
ngDebugContext: DebugContext_, 
ngErrorLogger: ƒ, …}
```

Comment: What is the name of your project/app in Firebase? As in what do you see in the Firebase console on the first line of the respective project's/app's card?

Comment: Try doing something like `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'some-app-name')` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: i have already tried @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: what version of firebase + angularfire are you on?

Answer (score 3):

Solution which worked for me :

```
npm uninstall --save firebase angularfire2
```

Then

```
npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with the same error. I resolved it by making sure the 

`"@firebase/app": "^0.3.3",`

dependency was up to date.

Comment: Thanks! `"@firebase/app": "^0.3.4"` is working for me together with `"@angular/fire": "^5.0.2"`

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this one,**

**Step 1:** Uninstall with the following command

```
npm uninstall --save firebase
```

**Step 2:** Now, open your package.json file. There, you will find:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"
```

**Step 3:** Below this line, add a this line (without the Caret(^) symbol): and save

```
"firebase": "4.8.0"
```

**Step 4:** Now do an npm install. Your app should work

Answer (score 0):

- npm uninstall --save firebase.
- In your package.json:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7",
"firebase": "4.12.1"
```

- npm i