# Firebase returns app/bad-app-name in Angular 6 and @angular/fire

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angular6, google-authentication

I am trying to add google user authentication with firestore. But the latest Angular 6 and @angular/fire are throwing some error.

My Package.json file are as follows:

```
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/fire": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
"firebase": "4.12.1",
```

The console error is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]: Firebase: Illegal App 
name: '[object Object] (app/bad-app-name).
[object Object]: Firebase: Illegal App name: '[object Object] (app/bad-app- 
name).
```

NOTE: I am not using old angularfire2 instead im using @angular/fire

Could anyone help to understand the breaking changes in new Angular 6 and fire modules

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase returns "app/bad-app-name" in angularfire2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369540/firebase-returns-app-bad-app-name-in-angularfire2)

Comment: Im not using angularfire2. I am using @angular/fire (formerly angularfire2)

Comment: I think you are confused. The @angular/fire project is old (see their repository, it is not updated from 1 year) and the angularfire2 project is new and maintained. Also for Angular 6, the angularfire2 library is officially supported. You should use the angularfire2 library.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the `firebase` package. I solved this by running:

```
ng update firebase
```